# How to restore (untrash) file with Google Drive V3?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm using C# Google Drive V3 Api. I need to restore some files from trash. I'm able to find programmatically the trashed files, but I cannot find any `Untrash` or `Restore` or similar methods. The only method related to Trash that I can find is `EmptyTrash` as shown in image below. How do I restore files then?

[image]

**Code**

```
public void Restore(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var driveService = DriveServiceFactory.Create();
    foreach (var file in GetTrashedFiles(from, to))
    {
        var newFileMetadata = new GoogleDrive.Data.File { Trashed = false };
        var updateReq = driveService.Files.Update(fnewFileMetadata, file.Id);

        updateReq.AddParents = string.Join(",", file.Parents);
        updateReq.Execute();
    }
}

public static class DriveServiceFactory
{
    public static DriveService Create()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                clientSecrets: GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                scopes: new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata },
                user: "user",
                taskCancellationToken: CancellationToken.None,
                dataStore: new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
                ).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "MyApp",
        });

        return driveService;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<GoogleDrive.Data.File> GetTrashedFiles(DateTime @from, DateTime to)
{
    var fileFieldsToQuery = "id, name, mimeType, size, createdTime, modifiedTime, md5Checksum, permissions(id, displayName, emailAddress, role), parents, trashed, trashedTime, trashingUser";

    var listRequest = _driveService.Files.List();
    listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
    listRequest.Fields = $"nextPageToken, files({fileFieldsToQuery})";
    listRequest.Q = "trashed=true";
    var filesFeed = listRequest.Execute();
    while (filesFeed.Files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in filesFeed.Files)
        {
            if (file.Trashed.Value && @from <= file.ModifiedTime && file.ModifiedTime <= to)
                yield return file;
        }

        // last page
        if (filesFeed.NextPageToken == null)
        {
            break;
        }

        // prepare the next page of results
        listRequest.PageToken = filesFeed.NextPageToken;

        // get next page
        filesFeed = listRequest.Execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion: Use the `files.update` method

Unlike V2, Drive API V3 dose not have a specific method for restoring trashed files. However, I suggest using the `files.update` method instead to restore files in trash. Before calling the method, ensure that the request body contains the file metadata with the following:

```
{
  "id" = "file_id";
  "trashed" = false;
}
```

**References:**

- [files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/update)
- [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files)

Comment: I tried it but I get `'The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Unauthorized. Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential`. Any ideas?

Comment: That might be due to an invalid/expired access token or your script might be sending an api key instead of an access token though it would be best if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your script in order for the community to further look into this. Also, I suggest ensuring that the scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` are declared in your script.

Comment: I figured out the credential issues and fixed it. But, though I do specify updateReq.AddParents the files are NOT restored to their original location. They are restored to the root of My Drive. I think if the parent folder doesn't exist yet it's restored to the root, which is My Drive. I included MRE just in case anyway

Comment: You're correct. If the parent folder specified no longer exists, the file will be restored to `My Drive`. However, the files should be restored to its previous location if the parent folder still exists. To confirm, are you getting the same behavior even if you remove `updateReq.AddParents = string.Join(",", file.Parents);`? By the way, file resource fields are case sensitive so you can also try replacing `file.Parents` with `file.parents`

Comment: Do you know why `trashedTime` is not populated? None of the fields show the date it was deleted. I deleted a file today. The api returns `trashed=true`, but the `trashedTime` is `null`. The `createdTime` and `modifiedTime` don't show todays date, but show when the file was actually created/modified.

Comment: I want to restore files from specific date. But, without `trashedTime` there is no way to do that. What is the alternative?

Comment: `trashedTime` is only populated for items in shared drives. If the item was deleted from `My Drive` or from a folder inside it, it's expected for `trashedTime` to return a null value. I recommend posting a new question regarding this as your current scenario has already shifted from the original topic of this post. A new, more specific post should also allow other, more knowledgable members of the community to provide alternatives, if there are any. Please do accept or upvote the answer if it was able to address your initial issue as well. Thank you